# How do I make the guard chase after the ninja in python and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make the guard chase after the ninja while you are trying to collect sushi. But when I try to run the code it just makes the guard move right (to where it runs off the screen but never comes back on the screen) and won't try to chase the ninja. I would like to be able to get the guard to chase the ninja while staying on the screen. I apologize in advance if my code does not full make sense. This is all new to me. I am currently using Python 3.2.5 to run this code. How do I get it to where the guard is chasing the ninja?

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 155, 0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Hungry Sushi Warrior')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
block_size = 40
SushiThickness = 40
GuardThickness = 50
FPS = 15

direction = "right"
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 18)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 40)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    paused = False

                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Paused",
                          black,
                          -100,
                          size = "large")
        message_to_screen("Press C to continue or Q to quit.",
                          black,
                          25)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)

def gamelives(lives):
    text = smallfont.render("Lives: "+str(lives), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [700, 0])

def score(score):
    text = smallfont.render("Score: "+str(score), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [0, 0])

def ninjaGuardGen():
    randGuardX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width-GuardThickness))
    randGuardY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height-GuardThickness))

    return randGuardX, randGuardY

def randSushiGen():
    randSushiX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width-SushiThickness))
    randSushiY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height-SushiThickness))

    return randSushiX, randSushiY

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to The Hungry Sushi Warrior",
                           green,
                           -100,
                           size = "medium")
        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat the different sushi",
                          black,
                          -30)
        message_to_screen("The more sushi you eat the faster the guards move and the more upgrades you get",
                          black,
                          10)
        message_to_screen("If you run into the edges or if you run into a guard you die!",
                          black,
                          50)
        message_to_screen("Press C to play, P to pause, or Q to quit.",
                          black,
                          180)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def guard(block_size, guardList):
    global guardHead

    if guardDirection == "rght":
       guardHead = pygame.transform.rotate(guardimg, 0)

    elif guardDirection == "left":
        gaurdHead = pygame.transform.rotate(guardimg, 0)

    elif guardDirection == "up":
        guardHead = guardimg

    else: 
        guardHead = pygame.transform.rotate(guardimg, 0)

    if len(guardList) == 1:
        gameDisplay.blit(guardHead, (guardList[0][0], guardList[0][1]))
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(guardHead, (guardList[-1][0], guardList[-1][1]))


def ninja(block_size, ninjaList):

    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(ninjaimg, 270)

    if direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(ninjaimg, 90)

    if direction == "up":
        head = ninjaimg

    if direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(ninjaimg, 180)

    if len (ninjaList) == 1:
        gameDisplay.blit(head,(ninjaList[0][0], ninjaList[0][1]))
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(head, (ninjaList[-1][0], ninjaList[-1][1]))

    # for XnY in ninjaList[:-1]:
        # pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [XnY[0], XnY[1], block_size, block_size])

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (display_width/2), (display_height/2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def gameLoop():
    guardStartX, guardStartY = ninjaGuardGen()
    global direction
    global guardDirection
    ninjascore = 0
    lives = 3
    direction = 'right'
    guardDirection = 'right'
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2

    speed = 15

    guardSpeed = 7

    guardX = guardStartX
    guardY = guardStartY


    guardXChange = guardSpeed
    guardYChange = 0

    lead_x_change = speed
    lead_y_change = 0


    guardList = []
    guardLength = 1

    ninjaList = []
    ninjaLength = 1

    randSushiX, randSushiY = randSushiGen()

    randGuardX, randGuardY = ninjaGuardGen()



    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game Over",
                              red, -50,
                              size = "large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play agian or Q to quit",
                              black,
                              50,
                              size = "medium")

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

            pygame.display.update()

        gameLives = False
        while gameOver == False:
            GuardDirections = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down']
            GetGuardDirectionNum = round(random.randrange(0, len(GuardDirections)))
            guardDirection = GuardDirections[GetGuardDirectionNum]
            if guardDirection == 'left':
                GuardXChange = -guardSpeed
                GuardYChange = 0
            elif guardDirection == 'right':
                GuardXChange = guardSpeed
                GuardYChange = 0
            elif guardDirection == 'up':
                GuardYChange = -guardSpeed
                GuardXChange = 0
            elif guardDirection == 'down':
                GuardYChange = guardSpeed
                GuardXChange = 0

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        direction = "left"
                        lead_x_change = -speed
                        lead_y_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        direction = "right"
                        lead_x_change = speed
                        lead_y_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        direction = "up"
                        lead_y_change = -speed
                        lead_x_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        direction = "down"
                        lead_y_change = speed
                        lead_x_change = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        pause()

            if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
                gameOver = True

            lead_x += lead_x_change
            lead_y += lead_y_change

            guardX += guardXChange
            guardY += guardYChange


            gameDisplay.fill(white)

            gameDisplay.blit(sushiimg, (randSushiX, randSushiY))


            guardHead = []
            guardHead.append(guardX)
            guardHead.append(guardY)
            guardList.append(guardHead)

            ninjaHead = []
            ninjaHead.append(lead_x)
            ninjaHead.append(lead_y)
            ninjaList.append(ninjaHead)

##            if len(ninjaHead) > ninjaLength:
##                del ninjaList[0]

            score(ninjascore)


            gamelives(lives)

            guard(block_size, guardList)

            ninja(block_size, ninjaList)

            pygame.display.update()

            if lead_x > randGuardX and lead_x < randGuardX + GuardThickness or lead_x + block_size > randGuardX and lead_x + block_size < randGuardX + GuardThickness:
                if lead_y > randGuardY and lead_y < randGuardY + GuardThickness:
                    randGuardX, randGuardY = ninjaGuardGen()
                    lives -= 1
                    if lives == 0:
                        gameOver = True
                        gameDisplay.fill(white)
                        message_to_screen("Game Over",
                                  red, -50,
                                  size = "large")
                        message_to_screen("Press C to play agian or Q to quit",
                                  black,
                                  50,
                                  size = "medium")
                    else:
                        gameOver = False

                elif lead_y + block_size > randGuardY and lead_y + block_size < randGuardY + GuardThickness:
                    randGuardX, randGuardY = ninjaGuardGen()
                    lives -= 1
                    if lives == 0:
                        gameOver = True
                        gameDisplay.fill(white)
                        message_to_screen("Game Over",
                                  red, -50,
                                  size = "large")
                        message_to_screen("Press C to play agian or Q to quit",
                                  black,
                                  50,
                                  size = "medium")
                    else:
                        gameOver = False

            if lead_x > randSushiX and lead_x < randSushiX + SushiThickness or lead_x + block_size > randSushiX and lead_x + block_size < randSushiX + SushiThickness:
                if lead_y > randSushiY and lead_y < randSushiY + SushiThickness:
                    randSushiX, randSushiY = randSushiGen()
                    ninjascore += 1

                elif lead_y + block_size > randSushiY and lead_y + block_size < randSushiY + SushiThickness:
                    randSushiX, randSushiY = randSushiGen()
                    ninjascore += 1

            if ninjascore != 0 and ninjascore % 10 == 0 and gameLives == False:
                lives += 1
                gameLives = True
                speed += 5
            elif ninjascore % 10 == 1:
                gameLives == False

            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

Comment: Please specify a specific problem and only post codes regarding that (**dont post your whole program**), you have way too much code to read and it's not even runnable (the images), This post will most likely not going to benefit any future readers.

Comment: okay, sorry about that. I am new to stack overflow. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

You have a bug in the guard direction code. Look for `GuardYChange = 10`. (Should be 0, I think.)

That said, I don't see any logic in the main loop that compares the guard's position with the ninja's. Try subtracting guard's X and lead's X, guard's Y and lead's Y, and comparing which of them is the bigger difference. Then have the guard go in that direction.

That is, something like this:

```
dx = lead_x - GuardX
dy = lead_y - GuardY

if abs(dx) > abs(dy):
    # chase left-right
    guardDirection = 'right' if dx > 0 else 'left'
else:
    # chase up-down
    guardDirection = 'down' if dy > 0 else 'up'
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make the guard chase after the ninja.